# How to retrieve HTML from Webbrowser control out of frames in .net (c#)

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, frames

I know that I can get the HTML (source code) of a Webbrowser control via:

HtmlDocument htmldoc = webBrowser1.Document

But this does only provide the html code of the "parent page". In case the webpage uses frames, it does not return the html code for the whole page including frames.

How can I get the complete HTML code including frames - or select a single frame and get the html code of that frame?

Answer (score 5):

```
 HtmlWindow frame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];

 string str = frame.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: If iframe has different url you will get UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 1):

my best option was:

```
WB1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml
```