# How to retrieve HTML from silverlight Webbrowser control out of frames

Tags: silverlight-4.0, webbrowser-control, frameset-iframe

i need to get the html of a frame inside the silverlight webbrowser control. i've looked at the following questions

[How to retrieve HTML from Webbrowser control out of frames in .net (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498719/how-to-retrieve-html-from-webbrowser-control-out-of-frames-in-net-c)

[accessing Frames rendered in webbrowser control in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026743/accessing-frames-rendered-in-webbrowser-control-in-c-net)

but they offer solution for WPF. how to do the same in silverlight webbrowser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this will be possible, since

> If you host content in an , all the regular security rules for iframes apply.

from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

and if i understand this line correctly, this means, you wont be able to access any content from within the iFrame.