# Does WebBrowser.DocumentText as well contains all frame documents text?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I am not sure if `WebBrowser.DocumentText` contains only top document source or frames document text also included. Could not find that from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not. I have tried next:

DocumentText:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\doc.txt", webBrowser1.DocumentText, Encoding.UTF8);
```

GetElementsByTagName("HTML")

```
HtmlElement elem;
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML");
    if (elems.Count == 1)
    {
        elem = elems[0];
        string pageSource = elem.OuterHtml;
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\doc.txt", pageSource, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

IOleCommandTarget

```
public void ShowSource()
{
    IOleCommandTarget cmdt = null;
    object o = null;
    object oIE = null;
    try {
            cmdt = (IOleCommandTarget)this.Document.DomDocument;
            cmdt.Exec(cmdGUID, oCommands.ViewSource, 1, o, o);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.InnerException);
    } finally {
            cmdt = null;
    }
}
```

The only way is to go through all frame documents.

**Updated** If iframe has different url you will get UnauthorizedAccessException [when trying to retrieve iframe document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498719/how-to-retrieve-html-from-webbrowser-control-out-of-frames-in-net-c)